# Caracteres extraños mysqli_set_charset

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

en mi **base de datos** le asigne como siempre el `utf-_Spanish_ci` para los acentos y demas esto va bien a ecepcion de la letra  **ñ** me la esta lanzando con un simbolo muy extraño un signo de interrogacion dentro de un diamante por asi decirlo intente poner en el archivo de conexion `mysqli_set_charset("utf8",$con)` esto funciono osea me arroja la letra **ñ** normal pero entonces las letras con acentos aparecen mal con mas simbolos extraños alguien puede decirme que esta pasando si tengo el cotejamiento de mi **base de datos** bien es decir `utf-_Spanish_ci` me imagino que es lo correcto

Comment: Tal vez poner el `CHARACTER SET` en `utf8` sirva, sino el `COLLATE` en `utf8_general_ci`, yo igual tuve ese problema con una base de datos, si eso no funciona prueba con `latin1`, de igual forma comprueba que donde estás viendo el output interprete los caracteres de forma correcta, que el HTML esté en utf8 o que la consola o terminal esté también en utf8. Para lo de collation y eso de la base de datos te dejo este link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html

Comment: Revisa si los datos están bien en la BD. Con charset `UTF-8` y collate `utf_spanish_ci` todo debería ir bien. Debes tener en cuenta otras configuraciones como el entorno PHP, HTML, etc ([ver aquí para más detalles](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967)). Puedes mostrar la constitución de la tabla y de cada columna haciendo un `SHOW CREATE TABLE elnombredelatabla`